# E_ADEPT_DOCUMENT_TYPE_UNKNOWN error in fulfilling a .acsm file

Tags: drm, google-play-books, adobe-digital-editions, acsm

I bought an ebook from Google Play Books: I may browse it from within Google Play; I can download the .acsm file (either for epub or for pdf version); but when I try to open it in Adobe Digital Edition 4.5.5 for Windows I get the error

```
Error getting License. License Server Communication Problem:
E_ADEPT_DOCUMENT_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
```

Looking at the .acsm file I noticed the suspicious line

```
<distributor>urn:uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001</distributor>
```

which is quite different from the one I got when loaning ebooks.

The only thing Google makes in such a case is to refund the book, which is not an actual answer; any idea of what's happening?

Comment: I assumed that you were able to download the acsm file, and that your error spawned when you tried to import the said file in ADE and download the actual book; if this is the case, would you be so kind to rephrase your question? Right now, it is a bit unclear if you have problems when downloading from Google Play or when importing to ADE.

Comment: is it clearer now? I confirm I have dowloaded the .acsm file.

Comment: Yes thanks. I know this was just nitpicking, but now it is better. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me with an `.acsm` file, but from a different store (it was Kobo); I managed to resolve this problem by downloading the file again, and Adobe Digital Editions was able to import it.
I don't really know what really happened in the background, maybe some error prevented the creation of a valid `.acsm` file; I can't guarantee that this will help you, but maybe it is a starting point.

Another possible suggestion, if you can't solve that way, is to get the refund from Google and buy the book from another store (I usually shop on Kobo and on IBS, the latter for the italian market is excellent)

*Said that, I highly respect and tend to privilege publishers that avoid all this stupid and bothersome DRM procedure (as a Linux user, I don't have a native solution to run ADE...); a policy that create problems only to paying customers is crap.*

Comment: I already tried to redownload the file, but still with no luck :-(

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any other clue. Have you already bought books from Google Play?

Comment: Last year,and it worked.

Comment: Could these be helpful? https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/y7ZN-jzkzT0 - https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/I8B1JaPUTxw

Comment: I already found out these threads, but still no luck.

Comment: Not sure if it's the same problem but now in 2020 the problem seems to be that Google servers return HTTP 302 redirect instead of the book content and ADE is unable to handle that. Reported both to Google https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/26905304 and Adobe https://community.adobe.com/t5/digital-editions/cannot-download-books-from-google-play-says-e-adept-document-type-unknown/m-p/10884632 but I don't think they'll notice me. :-/

Comment: My current workaround is: download the `acsm` file on an Android device, opening it with Adobe Digital Editions will download the `epub`, copy that to your e-reader. Cumbersome, but it works.

Comment: @riezebosch's solution is the only thing that's worked for me for either Kobo or Bibliovault with my fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 and ADE 2.0.1 on Wine.

Comment: @myersjustinc Turned out to be the `Content & Privacy Restrictions` on my MacBook that was blocking access to the download url.